# Duplicate objects during JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, uwp, httprequest, json-deserialization

I am having a strange issue where I am pulling a list of content from a Drupal site (by GET'ing paginated JSON data and deserializing to an object) and while I get the correct amount of objects, 51 of them are duplicates. This somewhat lines up with the default page[limit] of 50 that the JSON API provides, but I have overridden to a limit of 100 in my code.

Here is what I have found:

- I have a total of 1896 nodes I am retrieving data for, which matches how many objects I get.
- Of these 1896, ~51 are consistently duplicates.
- The duplicates are specifically the objects from indexes 1248 to 1351 of my dr_puppies array.
- Duplicates do not exist in the source data, and there doesn't appear to be any problems/inconsistencies with the source data.
- I printed a list of all URL paths I am requesting, and everything looks right (offsets increase by 100 appropriately, limit is always 100).
- There are about 19 total pages of data processed
- The issue is less that items are being duplicated, rather that the items are assumedly overwriting other valid objects in the array (I need to prevent the duplicates, not just get a Distinct copy of the array).

I don't have any code executing specifically near that point of the array generation, and there is not really anything significant about the index near 1248 (its about 70% of the way through the array generation).

The only thing I can think of is that maybe there is something wrong with the async call, but it hasn't been an issue before.

Here is the code that generates my array:

```html
private async Task RefreshPuppyData()
{
    dr_puppies = new Puppy();

    // Get the initial page of JSON data
    string initialJSON = await App.cmSession.LinkedSite.GetJSON("jsonapi/node/puppies?page[offset]=0&page[limit]=100");
    dr_puppies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Puppy>(initialJSON);
    
    // Check for additional pages of JSON data that need to be retrieved
    bool morePages = false;
    if (dr_puppies.links.next != null)
    {
        morePages = true;
    }

    // While there is a "next" link, process additional JSON data pages.
    while (morePages)
    {
        Puppy comboData = new Puppy();
        Puppy dataRetrievalTemp = new Puppy();

        // Fix the format of the "next" URL before query (square brackets instead of escaped text)
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(dr_puppies.links.next.href);
        builder.Replace("%5D", "]");
        builder.Replace("%5B", "[");
        builder.Replace("[limit]=50", "[limit]=100");
        builder.Replace("[offset]=50", "[offset]=100");
        dr_puppies.links.next.href = builder.ToString();

        // Get JSON for the next page
        string nextJSON = await App.cmSession.LinkedSite.GetJSON(dr_puppies.links.next.href);
        dataRetrievalTemp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Puppy>(nextJSON);

        // Combine data from current and previous page(s), copy to the user data.
        PuppyData[] oldData = dr_puppies.data;
        PuppyData[] newData = dataRetrievalTemp.data;
        comboData.links = dataRetrievalTemp.links;
        int newLen = oldData.Length + newData.Length;
        
        comboData.data = new PuppyData[newLen];
        oldData.CopyTo(comboData.data, 0);
        newData.CopyTo(comboData.data, oldData.Length);
        dr_puppies = comboData;

        // Exit the loop if there are no other pages.
        if (dr_puppies.links.next == null)
        {
            morePages = false;
        }
    }

    // Check the list for duplicates (occurs more than 1x)
    for (int i = 0; i < dr_puppies.data.Length; i ++)
    {
        int matches = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dr_puppies.data.Length; j++)
        {
            if (dr_puppies.data[i].attributes.title == dr_puppies.data[j].attributes.title)
            {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        if (matches > 1)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Duplicate puppy " + dr_puppies.data[i].attributes.title + " at index " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for GetJSON():

```html
public async Task<string> GetJSON(string getPath)
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
                if (getPath.StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    response = await Client.GetAsync(new System.Uri(getPath));
                } else
                {
                    response = await Client.GetAsync(new System.Uri(URL + getPath));
                }
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return jsonResponse;
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to get JSON data from the site: " + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: If you scrap all that list merging and just get a list of lists (you can flatten them later), are there still dupes? If you accept the site's limit of 50, are there still dupes?

Comment: Does webpage have java code running?  The java may be running in parallel causing the duplicates.

Comment: @jdweng As far as I know it doesn't, but I am just interacting with an API from the site, not loading a full webpage.

Comment: @Fildor - If I remove my code adding the limits it defaults to limit=50, which has the same issue and also takes almost 5x as long to query for some reason. (28secs vs 6 secs). About 45 duplicates there between indices 1799-1895. I can check the flat lists in a bit here.

Comment: @Fildor I added some code that outputs the title attribute of each data item from dataRetrievalTemp (this is the object deserialized from the JSON before it is combined with the previous data) and I still have duplicates.

Comment: I'm concerned about the links : if (dr_puppies.links.next != null)  With java code running in parallel you could have underruns/overruns.

Comment: @jdweng Well I don't have any code I set to run, I think it is just the base API. I checked the values of links.next for each execution and they all looked correct too, it wasn't skipping anything or doubling up on offset values.

Comment: Then there must be duplicates in the database.

Comment: I inspected a few of the duplicate entries from the app against the database and did not find any duplicates in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When I had similar problem, I used this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeData>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace });
```

From the documntation: *This sample deserializes JSON with ObjectCreationHandling set to Replace so that collection values aren't duplicated.*
Link: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObjectCreationHandling.htm

or this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeData>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings() { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

From the documentation: *By default Json.NET will serialize all objects it encounters by value. If a list contains two Person references and both references point to the same object, then the JsonSerializer will write out all the names and values for each reference.*
Link: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm

Comment: I will look into using some of the SerializerSettings you mentioned, but in general the problem isn't that there are duplicates that I want to remove - the problem is that there should not be any duplicates in the first place. If I removed the duplicates my dataset would be short ~50 rows.

Comment: I tried out both of these and it still produced duplicates, albeit much slower (115 secs vs my normal 6 secs)